# Print everything between pattern

Tags: awk, grep, pattern-matching

I would like to print everything between two two lines that match a certain pattern. For example, if my input file looks like

```
--- START ---
line 1
line 2
--- END ---
```

I would like to have as output

```
line 1
line 2
```

Can this be done (e.g. using grep or awk?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /^--- START ---\s*\n(.*?)--- END ---/s' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how to do it with `awk`

```
awk '/END/{f=0} f; /START/{f=1}' file.txt
line 1
line 2
```

You should easily find solution for this using Google.

Another version:

```
awk '/START/{f=1;next} /END/{f=0} f' file.txt
line 1
line 2
```

Comment: Should this still work if everything is on one line?

Comment: If all data is on one line, you need to use a `for` loop and test every field.  Post a new question on this if you like to see how, with example data and how you like your output.

Comment: Thanks. Perl seems to solve this at once in the slurp mode (indicated by "perl -0777")

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
sed -n '/--- START ---/,/--- END ---/{/--- START ---\|--- END ---/!p}'  < input
```

or

```
awk '/--- END ---/{exit}; flag {print}; /--- START ---/{flag=1} ' < input
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution which uses `awk` and `grep`:

```
awk '/-- START ---/,/--- END ---/ {print $0}' file.txt \
| grep -v -- '--- START ---' \
| grep -v -- '--- END ---'
```